# Общие параметры

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Можно ли задать параметры для всех Button/text/Label одной функцие, чтобы не писать к каждой кнопке одинаковые параметры? К примеру, я создал много однотипных кнопок для ввода данных калькулятора:

```
bttn1_1 = Button(root, text='MC', font='Arial 15', width=3, height=1, bd=4,
                 background='SkyBlue2', activebackground='green yellow')
```

Comment: Знаете что такое циклы и массивы?

Comment: Циклы, разумеется, знаю, а массивы редко использовал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так можно:

```
buttons = {}

for button_text in map(str, range(10)):
    button = Button(root, text=button_text, font='Arial 15', width=3, height=1, 
                    bd=4, background='SkyBlue2', activebackground='green yellow')
    buttons[button_text] = button
```

Кнопка с текстом `1`:

```
buttons['1']
```

---

Еще можно создать функцию которая обрезает/исправляет параметры:

```
def create_button(text):
    return Button(root, text=text, font='Arial 15', width=3, height=1, bd=4,
                  background='SkyBlue2', activebackground='green yellow')
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно опции для кнопок, созданных в разных местах кода, менять, изменив соответствующий стиль:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter.ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()
style = tkinter.ttk.Style()
for color in ['red', 'green']:
    tkinter.ttk.Button(
        text=color,
        command=lambda c=color: style.configure('TButton', background=c)).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Нажимая на любую из кнопок, изменяется цвет у всех кнопок со стилем `'TButton'` в данном случае.

Сгруппировать кнопки по своим стилям, можно используя `style` параметр: `Button(style='C.TButton')`.